# how do i specify the posittion in the table where the cell starts iterating?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have created a calendar from a table and I have to specify where it starts iterating in the first row of the table. I kinda want it to function like this.

[image]

so far this is my code in JS. I'm having trouble rewriting the for loop so that it would look like the calendar above

```
if (document.getElementById("daytxt").value == 1){

    // dynamically create the calendar based on inputs 

    var table = document.getElementById("mytable")
    var row = table.insertRow(2);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    for (r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        row = table.insertRow(r);
    for(c=0;c<7;c++){
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = c;
      }
    }
}
```

this is the product of the code

[image]

what do I change in my code so that my calendar would look like the first picture?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a initial value which will be your start day, also identify the no. of days a month can have, which will be your max no. of iterations. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wahab896/coqhxr34/54/) for your calendar code refer that or refer below changes:

```js
function createCalender(month, start_date) {
  const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  var monthName = monthNames[month],
    count = 1,
    initial_date = start_date - 1;
  var calendar = document.getElementById('calender');
  for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
    row = calendar.insertRow(count++);
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      if (initial_date && j == initial_date) {
        initial_date = undefined;
      }
      if (!initial_date) {
        cell.innerText = i;
        if (i < 31) {
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

createCalender(3, 5);
```

```html
<p>table</p>
<table id="calender">
<th>S</th>
<th>M</th>
<th>T</th>
<th>W</th>
<th>T</th>
<th>F</th>
<th>S</th>
</table>
```